# Can I Create an Order Product which ends after its parent Order?

Tags: validation, standard-objects, standard-field

I have a case where I would like to be able to be able to create an Order Product record with an end date that is *after* the end date on the parent order.

When I try to save the order product record I get an error:

> Error: An order product's End Date can't be later than Order End Date.

This also happens in a Developer Edition org so I think it's standard functionality.  Is there any way that I can disable this validation so that I can save an order product that ends after it's parent order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the line item may not start before the order, and may not end after the order. These are standard system validations.